# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output - while installing pycopy-fcntl through pip

Tags: python, django, pip

I was trying to install pycopy-fcntl via pip package installer but it was giving this error(newbie in stackoverflow).

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\lg\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bjhg1nur\\pycopy- 
 fcntl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
 bjhg1nur\\pycopy-fcntl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
 (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info- 
 00tiv3i6'
     cwd: C:\Users\lg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bjhg1nur\pycopy-fcntl\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lg\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\lg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bjhg1nur\\pycopy-fcntl\\setup.py'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I had tried this code `pip install --upgrade setuptools` still the error arrives.

I can't understand, what is the error telling about?

Thanks in advance, Sir/Mam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The source code](https://github.com/pfalcon/pycopy-lib/tree/e2400898b2a0fff40c3c5ec11b201858f85ff00f) doesn't have `setup.py`

[The package](https://pypi.org/project/pycopy-fcntl/0.0.4/#files) lacks almost all files including `setup.py`.

The bottom line: the package is either broken or is not intended to be installed with `pip`.